# What is the correct way to calculate the norm, 1-norm, and 2-norm of vectors in PyTorch?

Tags: python, vector, pytorch

I have a matrix:

```
t = torch.rand(2,3)
print(t)
>>>tensor([[0.5164, 0.3651, 0.0882],
        [0.4488, 0.9824, 0.4067]])
```

I'm following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/vector-norms-machine-learning/) introduction to norms and want to try it in PyTorch.

It seems like the:

- `norm` of a vector is "the size or length of a vector is a nonnegative number that describes the extent of the vector in space, and is sometimes referred to as the vector’s magnitude or the norm"
- `1-Norm` is "the sum of the absolute vector values, where the absolute value of a scalar uses the notation |a1|. In effect, the norm is a calculation of the Manhattan distance from the origin of the vector space."
- `2-Norm` is "the distance of the vector coordinate from the origin of the vector space. The L2 norm is calculated as the square root of the sum of the squared vector values."

I currently only know of this:

```
print(torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1))
>>>tensor([0.6385, 1.1541])
```

But I can't figure out which one of the three (norm, 1-norm, 2-norm) from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.norm.html) it is calculating, and how to calculate the rest

Comment: I think it is the `ord` parameter in the function. Try `print(torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1 , ord = 1))` for 1-norm and  `print(torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1 , ord = 2))` for 2-norm and see if it works.

Comment: I think that works! What about the `norm`?

Comment: Don't pass any argument and that should give you the norm. This `print(torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1 , ord = None))` or this `print(torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1))` should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To compute the 0-, 1-, and 2-norm you can either use [`torch.linalg.norm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.norm.html), providing the `ord` argument (`0`, `1`, and `2` respectively). Or directly on the tensor: [`Tensor.norm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.norm.html#torch.norm), with the `p` argument. Here are the three variants: manually computed, with `torch.linalg.norm`, and with `Tensor.norm`.

- 0-norm

  ```
  >>> x.norm(dim=1, p=0)
  >>> torch.linalg.norm(x, dim=1, ord=0)
  >>> x.ne(0).sum(dim=1)
  ```
- 1-norm

  ```
  >>> x.norm(dim=1, p=1)
  >>> torch.linalg.norm(x, dim=1, ord=1)
  >>> x.abs().sum(dim=1)
  ```
- 2-norm

  ```
  >>> x.norm(dim=1, p=2)
  >>> torch.linalg.norm(x, dim=1, ord=2)
  >>> x.pow(2).sum(dim=1).sqrt()
  ```

Comment: Thanks! What about the `norm`?

Comment: What you're referring to seems to be the 0-norm, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate norm of different order, you just have to pass in a `ord` argument with your desiered order. For example:

- `torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1, ord = 0)` should work for *norm*.
- `torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1,  ord = 1)` should work for *1-Norm*.
- `torch.linalg.norm(t, dim=1, ord = 2)` should work for *2-Norm*.
  And so on.

Comment: Actually calling `torch.linalg.norm` without specifying `ord` (or passing `ord=None`) defaults to the *2-norm*, not the *0-norm*.

Comment: Hum, so he either means inf norm or 0-norm.